# I need help understanding this recursive function (eloquent Javascript Chapter 17)

Tags: javascript

the recursive function calls cx.restore() at the end of the code.
Why does the function return to cx.rotate(2*angle) after cx.restore?

```js
let cx2 = document.getElementById("nummer2").getContext("2d");
let cx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

function branch(length, angle, scale) {
  debugger;
  cx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, length);
  if (length < 8) return;
  cx.save();
  cx.translate(0, length);
  cx.rotate(-angle);
  branch(length * scale, angle, scale);
  cx.rotate(2 * angle);
  branch(length * scale, angle, scale);
  cx.restore();
}
cx.translate(300, 0);
branch(60, 0.5, 0.8);
```

```css
.nummer2 {
  top: 500px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <style>

  </style>


  </svg>


  <canvas width="600" height="600"></canvas>
  <canvas id="nummer2"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

I used the debugger to understand the individual steps while executing the code.
According to my current understanding, a function stops after the last line.

Why does the recursive function continue to be executed after cx.restore()?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: A lot of cx.restores are going to get executed in this recursive function.  Are you looking at the last/outermost one?

Comment: I look at every cx.restore() and wonder why the function continues to execute even though return value: is undefined

Comment: "branch" doesn't explicitly return anything so undefined is expected.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have `</svg>` without `<svg>`

Comment: This is how recursion works. When the recursive call returns, you continue from the place where it was called in the previous invocation.

Comment: say you call branch.  it does stuff, then it calls branch (innerBranch).  The final instruction of innerBranch is cx.restore, and the next instruction of (outer) branch is the cx.rotate you are asking about.

Comment: Exactly, I get hung up on this thought. I'm in a function called again dozens of times and restore is called --> then rotate. Now I understand why the function doesn't end. The function is in itself and passes on to the previously called function.